# grails -functional tests won't run, even from within Intelli-J?

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, junit, functional-testing

I have a tests in `/test/functional` that extends `GrailsUnitTestCase`. When I run `grails test-app` they don't run, and when I try to run them from within Intelli-J, I get `no tests found`.

My test is simple enough, but I just don't see why it's not running. If I put it in `/integration/` or `/unit`/, it seems to run. I'm using grails `1.3.6`. Is there any reason `-functional` test-phase tests wouldn't run for me?

```
class MyServiceFunctionalTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    MyService myService

    public void setUp() {
        myService = new MyService()
    }

    public void testSomething(){
       assertTrue( true );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a functional test plugin installed? There's no direct support in Grails core for functional tests, so you'd want to install http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test or http://grails.org/plugin/geb or one of the other func test plugins.

I know your code is just an example, but it wouldn't make sense to either extend GrailsUnitTestCase or create a new instance of MyService (or even attempt to use dependency injection). Functional tests are really just clients of a running application that make GET and POST requests and verify the responses, so you won't have access to Spring beans, services, etc.

Comment: My services hit external systems that are guaranteed not to be running during the integration test phase. The functional test plugin has conflicting dependencies that don't seem fixable even with `transitive=false`. Is there an easy way to add a test phase *without* a plugin?

Also, the 1.3.6 and 1.3.7 documentation clearly states that *functional* and *other* are supported native test phases.

Comment: They're supported, but there's nothing in core to run them, start a server, etc. There are just hooks that functional test plugins can use.

Comment: Ah, I see. I really don't need to start a server, as I want to use the functional tests as REST method testing/selenium RC tests against an external system. Is there an easy way to add the running of the functional tests as if they were unit or integration?

Comment: You should ask on the User mailing list. Luke Daley has done a lot of work in this area and would probably be able to help you run a subset of your 'unit' tests (i.e. not functional or integration in the Grails sense but not mock-driven) as functional tests in their own phase.